# C++ Use undefined template in class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

Recently I discovered smart shortcut to predefine class in C++. Normally creating some complex structure I would write:

```
class A;
class B{
    A *a;
};
...
class A{

};
```

Now, thanks to shortcut, I write:

```
class B{
    class A *a;
};
class A{

};
```

My question - how can I make a short definition equivalent to this form:

```
template<typename T> class A;
class B{
    typename typedef A<class T> a;
};
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you can't. Using an elaborated type specifier for regular classes introduces the name into the enclosing namespace, by implicitly forward declaring it.

Templates aren't defined to behave the same way.

Comment: Well, I'll wait for someone who doesn't know you can't :)

Comment: @CheshireCat, you are free to read the c++ standard yourself. The answer won't change.